# Try, except and input

Tags: python-3.x

Two programs seperated by -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The program above the line is called program1
The program below the line is called program2
The only differens between the programs are int(input()) in program1 and input in program2

PS: I dont know what its called but in the text where I wrote "okd" (okayed) maybe I should write true?

The question/my line of thought:
In program1 `if number:` will be "okd" when `number == integer and number != 0`
In program2 `if number:` will be "okd" when `number == string and number != 0`
Does `if number:` check if `number` is what its trying to be in `Try:`
For example in program1  its trying to be an integer and in program2 its trying to be a string and in either program if number is what it tried to be it will be "okd" and the programs will `return number` and `break`?

```
def limit(question):
    while True:
        try:
            number = int(input(question))
        except:
            number = 0
        if number:
            return number
            break

question = "type an integer expressed with digits and press enter: "
number = limit(question)
print(number)
```

---

```
def limit(question):
    while True:
        try:
            number = input(question)
        except:
            number = 0
        if number:
            return number
            break

question = "type an integer expressed with digits and press enter: "
number = limit(question)
print(number)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of the `if` statement will NOT be evaluated if the expression given to it is `False`, 0, `None`, `''`, `[]`, etc.  The `if` statement will not try to detect if `number` is trying to be a string/int.

So if the user enters 0, then `number = int(input(question))` will run just fine, but number will be zero, so the body of the `if` statement will not be evaluated.

The purpose of the `try`/`except` is to check if the statements in the `try` body will run in to errors.  So if a user enters some numbers, then `number = int(input(question))` will run without any problems.  If a user enters something that is not an integer, then `number = int(input(question))` will give you a `ValueError`, and the `except` block will catch the error and be evaluated.

Comment: Does that mean that when the user of program2 types a string and press enter the variable number will become True and the body of the if statement will be evaluated?

Comment: The `number` variable will be a string (the value that you enter).  If that string is empty: `''`, then body of expression will not be evaluated.  Otherwise, it will be evaluated.

Comment: Does evaluate mean that the program will execute `return number` and `break` or just consider it? (in this particular case)

Comment: Yes, so if you enter something, then that string will be non-empty, and program will execute `return number` and `break`